# move rows in matlab vector to a new dimension

Tags: matlab, vector, multidimensional-array, matrix, reshape

I have the vector

```
output = PV_out(:);
```

I am trying to break this down into some sort of  form like -  output(K) where output(1) is the first 8760 rows, output (2) is the next 8760 rows etc etc

The vector above is a 236520x1 vector and so I am trying to get 27 "sets" of matrices
does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html):

```
%# old_output is 236520x1
%# desired is 8760 x 1 x 27 matrix 
new_output = reshape(old_output,8760,1,[]);
size(new_output) %# [8760 1 27]
   ans = [8760 1 27]
```

This will create an 8760x1x27 matrix where each row is taken sequentially from the vector that was given to it.  Note that you should be careful if you give it a *matrix* as the first input argument (rather than a *vector*): you should make sure you know in what order the values are being taken.  (Leaving the empty `[]` means it will automatically pick the right size for that dimension. You will still have an error if the `numel` of the input isn't evenly divisible by the dimensions you specify.)

Edit: changed dimensions according to comment below.

Comment: Definitely. How can I miss reshape :)

Comment: thanks, now I have the 27 row matrix how to I convert it to a 8760x1 vector where each set of 8760 elements represents one vector?

Comment: I am hoping to get things in some form like new_output(K) = ... where K represents the original K value above for each matrix set

Comment: You can either keep it as a matrix and get each row using `new_output(K,:)` **or** you can convert to a cell array: `output = num2cell(new_output,2);` and access each one using cell-indexing `output{K}` (note the curly brackets for indexing into a cell array).

Comment: so the code will read                                        new_output = reshape(old_output,27,[]);
new_output(K,:) %# first chunk of values ? Is this wat you mean. My problem is that I need this output in the A matrix of the linprog inequality constraint and so have to have it as a 8760x1xK vector for linprog to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

len = 8760;

out = zeros(len,27);

for i=1:27
  out(:,i) = output((i-1)*len + 1 : i*len);
end

Comment: I get the index exceeds matrix dimensions error on trying this code. Where can it be going wrong? is the for loop the only way about this ?

Comment: by preallocation the matrix out = zeros(len,27) are we not creating a 8760 x 27 matrix?

Comment: Yes, we are creating 8760x27 array. Isn't it what you want? I have checked. The code works just fine.

Comment: Also, please confirm if the above row does not account for elements twice. i.e I am trying to take the first 8760 elements, then the next 8760 (i.e 8761 - 17521) etc

Comment: Try this and u'll get your answer: output = 1:236520;
len = 8760;
out = zeros(len,27);
for i=1:27
out(:,i) = output((i-1)*len + 1 : i*len);
end

Comment: Also, prefer using 'reshape' as suggested by @tmpearce. But both the methods should work anyways.

Comment: Guys I think I haven't made my question clear enough - I apologise for this. please help me with making 27 sets of vectors where each set represents the old_output K matrix so I can have it in the form (which I need later in further code) new_output(K) = xyz

Comment: I originally started with - PV_out(:,:,K) = ... which is a 365x24x27 matrix. I then transposed this matrix in an attempt to form a 8760 x 1 vector row-wise (I believe reshape works column wise?). From there I am trying now to get the K sets of vectors that essentially represent the conversion of each row of PV_out to a column and then the stacking of each column - I hope this is clearer

Comment: Look, you've 3 dimensions here-X, Y, and Z. As I understood you want to transform each X,Y plane into a single vector of length 8760, keeping each X-Y plane values independent of the other. Right? Just use assignment operator in the loop: for i=1:K  temp = PV_out(:,:,i); out = temp(:); end. Now you can figure out the rest.

Comment: +1 for patience and being helpful. The community is better when people are both of those things. :)